# Accessing Disk Images on iOS

Tags: ios, dmg

Is it possible to mount and edit the contents of a .dmg file on an iPhone? I realize they are designed for macOS and larger computers of that ilk, but I'm curious if there's a workaround...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To my understanding, the only workaround involves jailbreaking the iOS device. If you are willing to try that route, you might find this helpful: https://www.reddit.com/r/jailbreak/comments/4hgr0y/tutorial_mounting_a_dmg_on_ios/.

If not, I don't believe there is any other way to mount a .dmg on an iOS device.